# AWS Lambda and Custom Classes

Tags: aws-lambda

Can someone explain how AWS lambda would know about any custom classes or methods I have written? Do you need to copy them into the zip file?

Basically I am outsourcing part of my server to Lambda where I have custom classes and methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the python files with the additional classes in your zip file and then you can do a regular `import foo` from your lambda. This is handy if you have a custom library that you need to use in several lambdas. See [Creating a Deployment Package (Python)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html).

Answer (score 0):

To do this in C# and create a not so microservice Lambda, yes I've done this, you can reference the other projects.  The trick is that these other projects also have to be AWS "Lambdas".  That way they have the same underlying dotnetcore references.  I don't think it is possible to take a standard framework dll and reference it.

Can you do this via reflection without a reference? Don't know.  If you needed to do that then you might as well just create another AWS Lambda and call it directly from another Lambda.  AWS Lambda to Lambda communication is very fast.  AWS Lambda to API Gateway to AWS Lambda not so much because of the added latency.  One could also do Step Functions which is really AWS Lambda to AWS Lambda with state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer in this scenario it is Python. My code has custom classes which I am assuming I would just upload and reference in my lambda python function? Are you saying this is a security risk?

Comment: I assume you can call other 3rd party apis from Python.  Why not call a python api of your own locally or make it another Lambda?  From what I can see, it can be challenging: https://codeburst.io/aws-lambda-functions-made-easy-1fae0feeab27